# How to Print triangle in vb.net listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print a triangle of 8 lines in a listbox control using vb.net. I have tried it many times but i am unable achieve it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, j, n As Integer
    i = 1
    j = 1
    n = 8
    While i <= n
        i += 1
        j = 1
        While j <= 1
            listbox1.items.add( "*" & vbCrLf)
            j += 1
        End While

    End While

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things right of the top of my head. In your second `While` statement you have `J <=1` instead of `J <= i`. But the main thing is that you are not building a string for your "*" and then adding that to your `ListBox`, instead you are adding individual item's for each * .

Here is one way

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, j, n As Integer
    i = 1
    j = 1
    n = 8
    While i <= n
        j = 1
        Dim tmp As String = "" 'String to build your Line
        While j <= i
            tmp += "*"
            j += 1
        End While
        ListBox1.Items.Add(tmp)
        i += 1 'Moved to end otherwise you start with 2 *'s
    End While

End Sub
```

and another using just one `While`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, n As Integer
    i = 1
    n = 8

    While i <= n
        ListBox1.Items.Add(StrDup(i, "*") )
        i += 1
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: @SyedAbdullah: If this answers your question, please mark it as such using the checkbox on the left.